# View.setClickable(false) but ACTION_DOWN events fired

Tags: android

I am trying to understand what clickable in Android means. I have a simple Button subclass which overrides onTouchEvent() and also implements OnTouchListener.onTouch() (returns false to let the event bubble up to the view) and I noticed that the callbacks are called with MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN (listener first, the view method later), and nothing more. I thought clickable = false disables touch events completely, but apparently not. What does it really do? How can I make sure the view doesn't get any touch events at all (setEnabled(false) seems not to work at all, events for ACTION_DOWN, _MOVE and _UP are fired unhindered).
Why are some touch events handled and other are not for clickable = false? I find it pretty surprising behavior and inconsistent - I would expect MotionEvent.ACTION_UP to be fired as well, but maybe click listeners should not be called. Any guidance?

**Update** With setEnabled(false) only the View.onTouchEvent method is called, the listener is ignored. Even stranger...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, setClickable is for calling the onClickListener when you click on it, and the actions like ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP are for handling finger events on the View within a OnTouchListener.

Comment: Maybe, but why is only ACTION_DOWN fired and nothing more? Why is the View.onTouchEvent method called even if the view is disabled? How to completely disable user interaction - something like userInteractionEnabled = NO in iOS?